# Regex that allows characters but fails on a cerain character repetition

Tags: regex

Hello I have the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,.()\s'#-]*$
```

it basically allows all apha numeric characters and , .  # -.

I would like to extend the regex to fail when there is a repetition of the special charaters.

for example:

test test ==> pass

test - test ==> pass

test -- test ==> fail

test ,, test ==> fail

test ## test ==> fail

Also if possible (but not necessary):

test #, test ==> fail

Please help .. and thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the start, such as:

```
^(?!.*?[,.()'#-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9,.()\s'#-]*$
```

See [test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rC6bD5/2)